# Is it possible to find an upper bound on the moment generating function of $\sqrt{|X|}$, where $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$?

Tags: inequality, definite-integrals, moment-generating-functions

So basically we need to find an upper bound on the integral $$\int_0^\infty \exp(f(x)) dx,$$ where $f(x) = \lambda \sqrt{x} - x^2/2$ with $\lambda>0$. I used the [Laplace's method of approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) and ended up with the following result, $$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\frac{\int_0^\infty e^{f(x)} dx}{g(\lambda)}=1,$$ for some function $g$, exact form of which is not relevant here. However, I am not sure how to use this method further to produce an upper bound of the integral of the following form $$\int_0^\infty \exp(f(x)) dx\le h(\lambda),\ \lambda>0.$$ Can anyone give any relevant suggestions or probably some reference that can help me progress in this direction? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We'll first consider the case when $\lambda > 0$.

Begin by writing

$$
\int_0^\infty \exp\!\left\{\lambda\sqrt{x}-x^2/2\right\}dx = \lambda^{2/3} \int_0^\infty \exp\!\left\{ \lambda^{4/3} \left(\sqrt{y}-y^2/2\right) \right\}dy.
$$

Near the maximum at $y = 2^{-2/3}$ we have

$$
\sqrt{y} - \frac{1}{2}y^2 = 3 \cdot 2^{-7/3} - \frac{3}{4}\left( y - 2^{-2/3} \right)^2 + O\left(\left( y - 2^{-2/3} \right)^3\right).
$$

Calculus (check the second derivative) shows that

$$
\sqrt{y} - \frac{1}{2}y^2 \leq 3 \cdot 2^{-7/3} - \frac{1}{2}\left( y - 2^{-2/3} \right)^2
$$

for all $y > 0$, and so

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \exp\!\left\{\lambda\sqrt{x}-x^2/2\right\}dx &< \lambda^{2/3} \int_0^\infty \exp\!\left\{ \lambda^{4/3} \left[ 3 \cdot 2^{-7/3} - \frac{1}{2}\left( y - 2^{-2/3} \right)^2 \right] \right\}dy \\
&< \lambda^{2/3} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\!\left\{ \lambda^{4/3} \left[ 3 \cdot 2^{-7/3} - \frac{1}{2}\left( y - 2^{-2/3} \right)^2 \right] \right\}dy \\
&= \sqrt{2\pi} \exp\!\left\{ 3 \cdot 2^{-7/3} \lambda^{4/3} \right\}.
\end{align}
$$

This upper bound agrees with the asymptotic of the integral up to the constant factor $\sqrt{2\pi}$. The correct asymptotic constant is $2\sqrt{\pi/3}$.

Now we'll suppose $\lambda < 0$.

In this case

$$
\int_0^\infty \exp\!\left\{\lambda\sqrt{x}-x^2/2\right\}dx < \int_0^\infty \exp\!\left\{\lambda\sqrt{x}\right\}dx = \frac{2}{\lambda^2},
$$

and this bound is asymptotically tight in the sense that

$$
\int_0^\infty \exp\!\left\{\lambda\sqrt{x}-x^2/2\right\}dx \sim \frac{2}{\lambda^2} \qquad \text{as } \lambda \to -\infty
$$

by Watson's lemma.

Comment: Yes, this answer matches the line of thought I was following to find an upper bound, thanks! So I see that the main step is bounding the second derivative (which is always $\le -1$ here) and bounding the last integral. I think a better bound might be achieved if some bound on error functions are used in the second step of the last integral evaluation, don't you agree?

Comment: If you did, the improvement would be exponentially smaller than the main term of the estimate. Practically it would be pointless.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer.

Comment: just a small typo, the factor of $\lambda^{2/3}$ will not be there outside the exponential.

Comment: Hi, I was wondering if there is any method to bound the integral when $\lambda<0$. The Laplace method does not see to work in that case. Can you please give any suggestion? I should have asked the question back when I posted this but I guess I did not think about this case then.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the $\lambda < 0$ case.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is about distributions, let's estimate the function
$$M(\lambda)=\sqrt{\frac2{\pi}}\int^\infty_0\exp(\lambda\sqrt{x}-\frac{x^2}2)\,dx.\tag1$$ In the spirit of Laplace's method, we're interested in the maximum of the integrand, which is attained at $$x_0=\mu(\lambda)=\left(\dfrac{\lambda}2\right)^{2/3}\tag2$$ 
But we won't approximate the exponent by a second degree polynomial, we'll estimate it from above. No polynomial with negative curvature will stay above $\sqrt{x}$, so we'll have to take the tangent ($\sqrt{x}$ is concave), and we take the tangent at $x=\mu$, of course, to be as accurate as possible near the maximum. Taking into account (2), we get $$\lambda\sqrt{x}-\frac{x^2}2\le\mu x+\mu^2-\frac{x^2}2=\frac32\mu^2-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}2,$$ so the final result will be $$M(\lambda)\le2\Phi(\mu)\,\exp\left(\frac32\mu^2\right),$$ where $\Phi$ is the cdf of the standard normal distribution, and $\mu$ is defined by (2). Since we had to ignore the non-linearity of $\sqrt{x}$, this will not be asymptotically optimal, but an overestimate by a factor of $\sqrt{7}/2<1.33$, I think. Of course, $\Phi(\mu)$ is almost $1$ for large $\lambda$.

Comment: The coefficient $5/4$ in your exponent is off. For $\lambda = 2$ you have $$M(\lambda) \approx 6.60644 > 5.87316 \approx 2 \Phi(\mu) \exp(5\mu^2/4).$$

Comment: @Antonio Vargas Thank you very much for your sanity check! I've corrected my blunder. Now, the estimate is $7.5382$, well above the true result (but not too much, as expected).

Comment: It's interesting that we got the same answer (modulo the factor $\Phi$) using very different methods.

Comment: @Antonio Vargas In fact, our methods start identically (same estimate of the exponent), but then, you make the somewhat rough estimate $$\int^\infty_0\ldots\,dy<\int^\infty_{-\infty}\ldots\,dy$$

Answer (score 0):

Because we have $$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\frac{\int_0^\infty e^{f(x)} dx}{g(\lambda)}=1$$ there is by definition of the limit an $N \in \Bbb N$ s.t. for all $\lambda \ge N$ we have $$\frac{\int_0^\infty e^{f(x)} dx}{g(\lambda)} \le 2$$ what gives us 
$$\int_0^\infty e^{f(x)} dx \le 2g(\lambda), \lambda \ge N$$

Additionally $$\int_0^\infty e^{f(x)} dx$$ is monotonous increasing in $\lambda$ and so $$\int_0^\infty e^{f(x)} dx \le 2g(N), \lambda < N$$  so we if we choose
$$h(\lambda) = \begin{cases} 2g(N), & \lambda < N \\ 2g(\lambda), &\lambda \ge N\end{cases}$$ we are done.

Comment: It's not that this idea has not crossed my mind, but the problem is that $N$ is unknown, or I do not see a method that allows me to estimate $N$. However, I upvoted the answer as it is pretty close to what I thought.

Comment: Without telling us your $g$ it won't be possible to help you estimating $N$. OFC $N$ is heavily dependent of $g$, to see this take any other non-negative function $b$ with $$\lim_{\lambda\to\infty} b(\lambda) = 1$$ and set $\overline{g} = b \cdot g$ then ofc also $$\lim_{\lambda \to \infty}\frac{\int_0^\infty e^{f(x)} dx}{\overline{g}(\lambda)}=1$$ but by the choice of $b$ you can "keep" the denominator close to $0$ as long as you want and "delay" the convergence.

Comment: Even with knowing $g$ how can you estimate $N$?

Comment: There is no general way or construction which always works… only a hope that for a suitable $g$ someone has a good idea :-)

Comment: and btw… still your question is not clear at all… just define $$h(\lambda) := \int_0^\infty \exp(f(x)) dx$$ and you have also an (quite trivial) "upper bound". So without adding some more information concerning the properties of $g$ or your upper bound the question is not specific enough.

Comment: I think I could not make my point clear. Can you find a closed form expression for the $h(\lambda)$ that you have defined? If you can't then the next step is to find a "good" upper bound for the same, right? That is exactly what I intend to do.